# Is decltype(std) legal, and does it have any purpose?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, decltype, compiler-bug

When using `decltype` around a namespace, I can write code that compiles, but the statement doesn't seem to have any effect under g++4.9.1, under clang it produces `error: unexpected namespace name 'std': expected expression`

For example, the following all compile under g++, but the assembly doesn't show any code generated for them.

```
using s = decltype(std);
auto n = typeid(decltype(std)).name();
auto sz = n.size();
std::printf("size is %zu\n", sz+1);
std::printf("this type is: %s\n\n", n.c_str());

// the only limit is your imagination
int f();
std::ostream trash = f(typeid(decltype(std)) * 10 - 6 ^ typeid(decltype(std)));
```

If g++ is right in allowing this? If so, what's the advantage of the code disappearing rather than causing a compile-time error?

Comment: Seems like a bug in g++.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not legal. The two *decltype-specifier* forms that are allowed by the grammar are (N3690, §7.1.6.2/1):

> *decltype-specifier:*
>       `decltype` ( *expression* )
>       `decltype ( auto )`

and a namespace name is not an expression.

The paragraph I quoted is from a standard draft post C++11, so `decltype(auto)` doesn't apply to C++11. The answer is the same, though.